# How to join Docker to a Windows domain?

Tags: windows, docker

I run a docker based on  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime and run an application insinde. When I check I see that this docker OS is in Workgroup.
Is it possible to join the docker to a Domain? I'd like to have a possibility to use domain\user accounts in my app etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you need to use gMSAs.

From Microsoft website:
“… Windows containers cannot be domain joined, they can still use Active Directory domain identities to support various authentication scenarios. To achieve this, you can configure a Windows container to run with a group Managed Service Account (gMSA)…”

There are a few things that you need to do in your AD, I recommend that you follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts)